# How can I access my ListView to add items from a separate class on C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ListView item on Form1 and I have a separate class named Common that handles some functions. My problem is I can't access it directly to add items. Tried finding some useful resources but still can't manage to make it work. Here's my code:

Form1

```
namespace myTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void tempAddToList( ListViewItem items )
        {

            ListView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { items });

        }
    }
}
```

Common.cs

```
namespace myTest
{
    class Common
    {
        private Form1 mainForm;

        public Common()
        {

        }
        public Common(Form1 mMainForm)
        {
            mainForm = mMainForm;
        }

        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("1");
        item1.SubItems.Add("1");
        item1.SubItems.Add("2");
        item1.SubItems.Add("3");
        item1.SubItems.Add("4");
        item1.SubItems.Add("5");
        item1.SubItems.Add("6");
        item1.SubItems.Add("7");
        item1.SubItems.Add("8");

        mainForm.tempAddToList(item1);
    }
}
```

Basically calling **mainForm.tempAddToList(item1);** doesn't work. I always get

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myTest.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

**Additional question**: Can I access ListView1 from Form1 so that I can call and add directly on Common? For example

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("1");
item1.SubItems.Add("1");
item1.SubItems.Add("2");
item1.SubItems.Add("3");
item1.SubItems.Add("4");
item1.SubItems.Add("5");
item1.SubItems.Add("6");
item1.SubItems.Add("7");
item1.SubItems.Add("8");
Form1.ListView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { items });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work". What were you expecting, and what actually happen? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Also, where are you ever calling the constructor for `Common` (with the overload)?

Comment: You need to be sure that you're on the form1 UI thread when calling add.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The code that construct the ListViewItem is outside from any method of class Common

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: It's winforms, not xaml...

Comment: @code4life What difference does that make? Events and EventHandlers exist in both technologies. They are a feature of C#.

Comment: @gunr2171 get An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myTest.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please edit your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: his link pointed to the XAMLversion, not sure if you noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid.
The lines of code that add to the ListViewItem should be inside a method of the class Common

```
namespace myTest
{
    class Common
    {
        private Form1 mainForm;

        public Common()
        {

        }
        public Common(Form1 mMainForm)
        {
            mainForm = mMainForm;
        }

        public void AddItemToListView()
        {
            if(mainForm == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Class instance intialized with wrong constructor!");

            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("1");
            item1.SubItems.Add("1");
            item1.SubItems.Add("2");
            item1.SubItems.Add("3");
            item1.SubItems.Add("4");
            item1.SubItems.Add("5");
            item1.SubItems.Add("6");
            item1.SubItems.Add("7");
            item1.SubItems.Add("8");

            mainForm.tempAddToList(item1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you coud write when you have a Form1 instance available

```
 Common cm = new Common(instanceOfForm1);
 cm.AddItemToListView();
```

Notice that you need to construct an instance of the class Common with the constructor that takes an instance of Form1 otherwise calling on a null instance will raise a NullReference Exception.
A check before adding items to the ListView could protect your code from this exception.

Comment: tempAddToList() is on Form1 so useless that I call this back and forth on Common.

Comment: Can you explain then why you need a class Common with this functionality?

Comment: Common stores db connection and some functions. It's like a Common function for all forms on my project.

Comment: In this answer, it would be best to exclude the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @ErikPhilips of course, but the poster says that this is just a part of the functionality of the class. So perhaps the empty constructor is needed for other purposes.

Comment: Still it is unclear when and where this functionality to add item to the Form1 instance is needed. Perhaps, if the class was static and used from time to time to add ListViewItems to the main form....

Answer (score 0):

You never call the mainFormObject mMainForm. Instead of

```
mainForm.tempAddToList(item1);
```

Try

```
mMainForm.tempAddToList(item1);
```

Comment: `mMainForm` goes out of scope as soon as the constructor is complete. The code is being called in another function (not downvoting because that _could_ have been in the constructor, but it is unclear if it should).

Comment: Ahh, very true. Thanks for that. Sorry @wpleet